# WiX custom action by platform

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I need to create a checkbox to install drivers after installation of program (just like run program checkbox). Additional problem is that driver depends on platform of system. I'm trying to do it like that:

```
<CustomAction Id="RunProgram" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]Application.exe" Return="asyncNoWait"/>
<CustomAction Id="RunDriver64" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]driver/Installer_x64.exe" Return="asyncNoWait"/>
<CustomAction Id="RunDriver32" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]driver/Installer_x86.exe" Return="asyncNoWait"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunDriver64" After="InstallFinalize">'$(var.Platform)' != 'x64'</Custom>
  <Custom Action="RunDriver32" After="InstallFinalize">'$(var.Platform)' == 'x64'</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<UI>
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Order="2" Event="DoAction" Value="RunProgram">
    WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX
  </Publish>
</UI>`
```

but it doesn't work. Error message:

> Error 1   ICE03: Bad conditional string; Table: InstallExecuteSequence, Column: Condition, Key(s): RunDriver64    F:..path..\Product.wxs  26  1   ..project name..

Also my solution is not perfect, as I'm running there a action I don't realy want 'RunProgram', but I couldn't create empty action. Any suggestions, how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap it in [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Try `<![CDATA[NOT(VersionNT64)]]>` and `<![CDATA[(VersionNT64)]]>` instead of `'$(var.Platform)' != 'x64'` and `'$(var.Platform)' == 'x64'`

Comment: Okey, that prevents error. Do You maybe know, how can I solve 2nd problem to connect one of those 2 actions to Publish element? I was trying to run it before some other empty custom action called by publish, but I cannot create empty custom action

Comment: Publish can have conditions. If you look here, you'll see an example PIDACCEPTED="0". http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/control-your-controls and then you can condition on the standard Windows Installer properties like VersionNT64 etc